# jQuery. Filtering out list items

Tags: jquery

My html is about a searchbox

```
<input type="text" id="myInputList" placeholder="search...">
```

and a list of checkboxes rendered via

```
<ul class="list-group container" id="myList">
    @foreach (var v in Model)
    {
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx custom-control-input" id="@v.GuidId.ToString()">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="@v.GuidId.ToString()">@v.Name</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

By using the following i can filter out the desired info

```
$("#myInputList").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li").filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
});
```

Now i wish to extend the functionality by using three buttons

```
<div id="Group" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" style="width:100%" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="b1" active">
        <input class="selected" type="radio" name="options" checked="checked"> All
    </label>
    <label id="b2">
        <input class="selected" type="radio" name="options"> Checked
    </label>
    <label id="b3">
        <input class="selected" type="radio" name="options"> Unchecked
    </label>
</div>
```

Upon clicking `b1`, i wish to show all li's

by clicking `b2`, display the li's where child checkboxes are checked and

by clicking `b3`, display the li's where child checkboxes are unchecked.

For `b1` this one works great

```
$("#b1").on("click", function () {
    $("#myInputList").val("");
    $("#myInputList").trigger("keyup");
});
```

but what about `b2` and `b3`?

Comment: @MuhammadSami Do not know how to do it?

Comment: The third snippet should use `each()` instead of `filter()`.  You are not using the result of filter, and are just using it to iterate, so that is an improper usage.

Comment: Also, from a UI point of view, this is a very weird user experience, using the text box to drive the filter by text **or** checked state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On change of radio buttons you need to filter `li` by the `checked` status of checkbox inside it and show / hide.

```js
$("input[name='options']").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  var $li = $('#myList li').hide();      

  if (id == 'b1') {
    $li.show();
  } else if (id == 'b2') {
    $li.filter(function() {
      return $(this).find('input').is(':checked');
    }).show();
  } else if (id == 'b3') {
    $li.filter(function() {
      return !$(this).find('input').is(':checked');
    }).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Group" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" style="width:100%" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label id="b1">
    <input class="selected" type="radio" name="options" checked="checked"> All
  </label>
  <label id="b2">
    <input class="selected" type="radio" name="options"> Checked
  </label>
  <label id="b3">
    <input class="selected" type="radio" name="options"> Unchecked
  </label>
</div>

<ul id="myList">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx custom-control-input" checked>
      <label class="custom-control-label">Name 1</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label">Name 2</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx custom-control-input" checked>
      <label class="custom-control-label">Name 1</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label">Name 2</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx custom-control-input" checked>
      <label class="custom-control-label">Name 1</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label">Name 2</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```